# How can I quit my job before my 6 month probation and before my 2 years service and jump ship without getting the dubai ban?

Tags: working-visas, uk-citizens, uae

If I jump ship for a higher salary before my 6 month probation or better yet; before my 2 years of service at my current employer; I have heard I will be banned for 6 months to work. Apparently you can pay or do something to address this?

Comment: Is this in the UK? What is "dubai ban"?

Comment: @littleadv A ban from Dubai?

Comment: Instead of editing my answer, please add your information as a new answer. You can then accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find much information about immigration to the UAE. The official webpage with the relevant information might be http://dnrd.ae/en/Rules_Reg/Pages/Rules.aspx?AudianceId=3, but it looks sketchy for an official government webpage. This [random webapge](http://www.guide2dubai.com/info/labor-immigration-ban.asp) has a lot of information about the visa ban. I think the relevant section for you is

> It is possible to avoid a ban/ lift a ban by paying a fee, in case you are transferring from one sponsor to another. This is different from cancelling your residence visa or work permit. It is not clear if a NOC (No Objection Certificate) from employer is necessary for processing this. However, for exact details of ban lifting fee (which may vary depending on certain occupations), it is better to check with the labour department helpline of the emirate you are working in.

Comment: I have heard that certain salaries and people with higher certifications such as UK attested degree holders may skip the ban. The ban seems to be for all the Indian, Pakistan and Filipino workers; like construction trades.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid it sounds like there are lots of "unofficial rules" and the only thing helpful in my answer is really "check with the labour department helpline of the emirate you are working in"

Comment: That is Dubai for you man! I love this place!

Comment: A ban which restricts new migrants to one employer, a government-enforced fine enforcing the ban, I can only imagine what that system does to the social and economic position of the migrants. Pity on them.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer In the UK [changing employers on a Tier 2](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/extend-your-visa) requires paying a £650 fee so I I don't think the behaviour is particularly rare.